# Send Google Cloud Messages

Tags: performance, php, mysql, json, curl

I wrote code which is doing query and insert inside `while` loop.

```
    $getall = mysql_query("SELECT `deviceid`,`uid` FROM  `users` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`bgroup`,  '".$allbrgou."' ) AND `uid`!='".$from."'");
while($mdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($getall)){
        $newto = $mdata['uid'];

        $result = mysql_query("insert into request(rto,rfrom) values ($newto,$from)");


        $message="You get Request From ".$row['name'] ;
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $did=$mdata['deviceid'];

            $fields = array(
                            'registration_ids'  => array($did),
                            'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
                            );
            $headers = array( 
                                'Authorization: key=xxxxxx',
                                'Content-Type: application/json'
                            );

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

}
```

This code on shared hosting took 2 min with just 120 records.  Will concatenation and executing insert query fix this performance issue?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.